# How do I view text files in a bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a php web application whereby, a list of files(text) are displayed in a tabular form with buttons to view ,edit or delete  each file.

On click of the view button of any file, it should display a bootstrap modal with the content of that particular file . I have not been able to achieve that so far .

How will I be able to view the content of files in a modal ? Thank you .

Edit :  I strongly suspect it has to do with the php code that reads the contents of the files in the directory . I am sure, I am not doing something right .Specifically, how can a click on a particular view button  display a particular file . Any help with regards to the php code will be highly appreciated .

```
 <?php
           $path='/path/to/files';
           $myDirectory=opendir($path);  

           if ($myDirectory==false)
     {
        echo "<br><br><div class='container'><div class='alert alert-danger text-center'><strong>Error!</strong> Failed to open Directory </div></div>\n";
         break;
     }

           //Gets each entry
           while($entryName=readdir($myDirectory))
           {
               $dirArray[]=$entryName;
           }     

           closedir($myDirectory);
           $indexCount=count($dirArray);
           sort($dirArray);


           //loops through the array of files 


                     foreach ($dirArray as $value) {
                       # code...

                       $text=file_get_contents('/path/to/files/'.$value);

                       $content=str_replace("\n","<br>",$text);
                         $conn[]=$content;

                     }



           for($index=0; $index < $indexCount; $index++)
           {

                     $name=$dirArray[$index];

                   if ( ( strpos($name,'.') === 0 ) | $name == "." | $name == ".." ){
                                        continue;
                        }

                     print("

                      <tr>

                      <td><span></span><a href='$name'> $name <a></td>
                      <td>$path</td>

                      <td class='text-nowrap'><button type='button' class = 'btn btn-default' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' > View </button></td>

                      <td><button class = 'btn btn-default' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#edit'> Edit </button> </td>

                      <td><a href='delete.php?name=".$name."'><button class = 'btn btn-default' > Delete </button></a></td>

                      </tr> 


                  ");



           }     






?>

 <div class='modal fade' id='myModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel'>
              <div class='modal-dialog' role='document'>
                <div class='modal-content'> 
                <div class='modal-header'> 
                 <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-label='Close'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'></h4>
               </div> 
                <div class='modal-body'> 

                   <div> <?php 

                      //print_r($conn)  


                          foreach ($conn as $key => $value) {

                               echo $value;

                          }
                   ?> </div>
                   <div>

                   </div>                  

 </div>
                 <div class='modal-footer'>
                  <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>   
                     </div>   
                </div>   
                 </div>  
                </div>
```

Comment: Please show us your code as well and where did you get stuck. This will help people with identifying the issue(s). And welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you, @plamut . I have included my code now .

Comment: Good! I hope you get an answer you are looking for!

Comment: @user3744370 Let me know if my answer helps you

Comment: @Reddy Thanks for your help . When I use the <iframe> tag it breaks the code . ie it only shows a file in the table and  it fails to launch the bootstrap modal even though I have changed the path.

Comment: It might be some other code breaking in your end. As you can see the demo works fine. May be yo have to show your code with table and what is breaking  for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't working because you are duplicating your modal for every row in your table. They all have the same id so Bootstrap will get confused about which you want to open. You need just one modal anywhere on the page and to pass the data to the modal via Javascript to update its content. Here's the code I've taken from the Bootstrap website:

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    var file_contents = button.data('filecontents') // Extract info from data-* attributes
    // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
    // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
    var modal = $(this)
      modal.find('.modal-body').html(file_contents)
})
```

Then add your file contents to a data attribute:

```
<td class='text-nowrap'><button class = 'btn btn-default' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-filecontents="$content"> View </button></td>
```

Reference:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Thank you @Thomas Illingworth  for the answer .  I implemented the solution as you stated but I can still view the content of one file as the content of the rest .  I strongly suspect it has to do with the php code that reads the contents of the files in the directory . I am sure I am not doing something right . Any help with regards to the php code will be highly appreciated .

Comment: @user3744370 You are overwriting $content each time you run your foreach. Is there any reason you can't output in the foreach instead of using the for loop? This means you could just echo it out then. Otherwise you're going to have to turn $content into an array and access it that way

Comment: I followed your suggestion and turned $content to an array . Now when I access it (ie click on the button of a particular file) it now shows me the content of all the files in one modal instead of the content of a single modal . How can I access the content of a particular file  at a time .

Comment: thanks for your continuous support .I have updated my original question with the updated code .

Comment: You don't want to echo out any php inside your modal. You need to add the data param data-filecontents="$conn[index]" and use the javascript I supplied.

Comment: This is the error am getting when I try that "PHP Notice:  Undefined index: value"     ----> <td class='text-nowrap'><button class = 'btn btn-default' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' data-filecontents='$conn[value]' > View </button></td>

Comment: Try using $conn[$index]. But it depends if $index matches the index of your files. You could move all your code into the foreach though using foreach ($dirArray as $index => $value). This would make it more simple but you might have to make some tweaks though

Comment: Thanks a lot @Thomas it finally worked, I can now view a particular file at a time . I implemented your suggestion and moved the code into the foreach statement instead and used the $conn[$index]  . Once again really appreciate the help given.

Answer (score 0):

In order to view a file in browser you can do this, Put a iframe inside your modal body and then set the `src` attribute of the modal to point to your file path.

```
 <div class='modal-body'> 
   <iframe src="xxx.com/yourFile.txt" width="800px" height="600px" >
 </div>
```

Here is a Snippet to demonstrate the same.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  View File
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe src="https://wordpress.org/plugins/about/readme.txt" width="550px" height="400px" >
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** In this example you cant see the file because of the cross-origin rule, Browser stops it. But if you give a path to your same server then you should not have any problem.